# Password for user 'sa' automatically changing daily

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Password for user `sa` automatically changing daily. I have unchecked the `enforce password policy` but no use. Just tell me from where to change the setting of this login to not to change password after interval of time.

I always had to login with Windows authentication. Mode and change password to use DB.

I know this question is asked by someone else but no one got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem .

When i change my windows it fixed! i think this is one virus or some things like that.

But now i suggest you visit this link : [link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1007864-sa-password-keep-changing-automatically.html)

SA passwords don't change or reset automatically. As he suggests, look at (or enable) some logging that will let you see what's up. Also, see if there are any services that execute in the middle of the night that may have SA permissions. Are there any system restores or other kinds of things happening? It is unlikely that anything like that will be changing the password but it's something to look at.

or visit this [Link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/sa-password-automatically-changed.3943/)

In SQL Agent Section, their is a Jobs folder..in this malware exist..delete all viruses and useles jobs except the system jobs or u have defined..it worked for me :)

Comment: are u sure password for'Sa' don't change automatically..because i saw this problem is also with other people too..and their is no such mid night activity kind of thing in my server..i visited the link but no use..any other idea ?

Comment: i saw this too. but i think this is a malware or ...

Comment: Hey loup i think i got it...there are too many jobs assigned to users ...i mean there are viruses/malware..some writen in chinees..some wre hc.exe..server.exe..stupid..:s i deleted all those also they are scheduled to run in mid night :D..aniwayz..thanks..by chance i went to jobs section :)

Comment: I deleted these jobs, but after some days such jobs (named "vb" or "x" for example) created automatically and my "sa" password was changed. Any idea?

Comment: I thinks you have a virus or malware in your OS. Install a good anti virus or change your OS.